# Indented new line when creating a new block in C

Tags: c, vim

I am using the [AutoClose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) plugin in Vim. I would like to set the behaviour so that when I am in the state

```
while(i < N) {<cursor>}
```

then when (and only when) I press return, I get to:

```
while(i < N) {
    <cursor>
}
```

This is the behaviour in Sublime Text.

There is a similar question here: [Automatically insert a matching brace in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521818/automatically-insert-a-matching-brace-in-vim) but there the user is looking to start a new line as soon as the opening brace is created. Also it doesn't seem to work correctly for me.

If I use that, or do `set cindent` as suggested by @WoLpH the result is (as soon as I create the opening brace)

```
while(i < N) {
     <cursor>
    }
```

as in the second brace is indented and the cursor is indented by one space. My vimrc settings are:

```
filetype indent on
set ts=4
set sw=4
set et
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the AutoClose script. Function `OpenSpecial` now contains:

```
return "\<esc>a\<CR>\<tab>;\<CR>".a:cchar."\<esc>\"_xk$\"_xa"
```

So I get my desired behaviour by typing `{{`l, good enough for now

Answer (score 0):

There's a build-in feature for that, it's called `cindent`.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#.27smartindent.27_and_.27cindent.27

So, just put this in your `.vimrc` and it should work:

```
set cindent
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm after - I'll update the question with what happens there

Comment: @MrE: yes, you need a few other flags as well to get it working properly. In my case the `}` automatically gets dedented after typing.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are after is included in [DelimitMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754), another plugin similar to AutoClose.

For what it's worth, I've stopped using any autoclosing plugin a couple of months ago but I kept that "bracket expansion" feature with this line in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>==<C-o>O
```