# Vim scroll jumps when opening brackets / braces / etc

Tags: vim

Experiencing some annoying scrolling when I open a new set of brackets / braces as I'm typing in vim and not too sure about the source of my problem? Not too sure how to describe so [here's a gfycat showing the jumping](https://gfycat.com/HarmlessAmpleIlsamochadegu). Super annoying if I'm trying to write some code while looking at something above it...

For reference here are the settings I have in my .vimrc:

```
set smartindent
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set number
set encoding=utf-8
set laststatus=2
set noshowmode
set term=screen-256color
set nocompatible
set backspace=2
set foldmethod=indent
set nofoldenable
set foldlevel=20
set foldnestmax=10
set background=dark
syntax on
```

I use this packages:

```
'scrooloose/nerdtree'
'vim-airline/vim-airline'
'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
'mutewinter/swap-parameters'
'kien/ctrlp.vim'
'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
'tpope/vim-sleuth'
'ekalinin/dockerfile.vim'
'google/vim-jsonnet'
'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
'SirVer/ultisnips'
'honza/vim-snippets'
```

Comment: It's your auto-pairs plugin which is creating the closing bracket, and may well also be causing the jumping behaviour. Try to disable/remove that plugin and see if it helps.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's generally good practice to have a close bracket when you open one, so that you might not forget about it later, but if you really want to get rid of it, I think this thread does a pretty good idea of explaining how to rebind it:
[Automatically insert a matching brace in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521818/automatically-insert-a-matching-brace-in-vim)

Comment: Hmm so I suppose I see how turning that off might fix my problem, but vim by default in my setup already  creates the close bracket right after I open the bracket and it's the <CR> that's the problem right?

Answer (score 0):

As nickspoon said, auto-pairs plugin was the culprit.